# Anonymous lifetime in function return type

Tags: rust

I was looking at the source code of Rust, and found [this function](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2c6a29af35a81e20f8af4c32bf1b55c59b89eccd/compiler/rustc_lexer/src/lib.rs#L230).

```rust
pub fn tokenize(input: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = Token> + '_ {
    let mut cursor = Cursor::new(input);
    std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        if cursor.is_eof() {
            None
        } else {
            cursor.reset_len_consumed();
            Some(cursor.advance_token())
        }
    })
}
```

I understand that '_ refers to an [anonymous lifetime](https://yegeun542.github.io/rust-edition-guide-ko/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/the-anonymous-lifetime.html), but I'm not sure what it means in this context. Would love to get some clarification on this. Thanks.

Comment: it's the same lifetime than input reference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a shorthand for

```rust
pub fn tokenize<'a>(input: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = Token> + 'a { ... }
```

Rust sometimes allows you to avoid declaring lifetimes when the declaration is unambiguous:

```rust
fn foo(input: &'a str) -> &'a str { ... }
// same as
fn foo(input: &str) -> &str { ... }
```

But in the code above, the return type is not a reference, so this shorthand can't be used. `'_` is a syntactic sugar for this case.

But why can't the `'_` be eluded, too? Here's the answer from [RFC 2115: argument_lifetimes](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2115-argument-lifetimes.html#structs-and-lifetimes):

> The '_ marker makes clear to the reader that borrowing is happening, which might not otherwise be clear.

Comment: I can’t understand why you need to specify a lifetime here since you are not returning a reference. Could you explain it better?

Comment: You are actually returning a reference, but it's wrapped in an `Iterator`.

Comment: I cannot see why is returning a reference (in some way), since the method _seems_ returning an instance of struct `FromFn` that implements the `Iterator` trait. If I got it right `impl Iterator` means "something that implement `Iterator` trait that I am too lazy to type (and let the compiler infer for you)"